# how to replace every first decimal number of line with binary number w/o effecting other words

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to convert a first decimal word of every line to binary without affecting any other words.

My code is as follows:

```
use strict;

use warnings;

open (tf, "dec.txt");
open (out1, " > bin.txt");
while (my $line = <tf>){
    my $binary_number = sprintf("%03b", $line); 
    print out1 " $binary_number\n";
}
close (tf);
```

***input file example:***

```
3 4 5 
6 7 2
1 2 3
```

***expected output:***

```
011 4 5
110 7 2
001 2 3
```

***o/p from the code:***

```
011
110
001
```

---

Is there any suggestion to achieve o/p file as per expected output? I am missing other words in the line here. those words I want to print as it is.

and also another question:
is there a way to read a single column (not line)?

for example in above o/p 1st column ...

```
0
1
0
```

Comment: `printf out1 "%03b %s %s\n", split ' ', $line;`  Note that global filehandles are by convention uppercase (TF, OUT1), but lexical filehandles are preferred: `open( my $tf, ... ); while (my $line = <$tf>)...`.  Also, 3-arg open is preferred: `open( my $out1, '>', 'bin.txt' )` and some builtins will give you trouble if you parenthesize but leave a space between the builtin name and the `(`, so avoid doing that.  Lastly, `use autodie;` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+)/sprintf("%03b",$1)/e' inputfile.txt
```

`s///e` will execute the replacement as Perl code and replace the match with the result, leaving the rest unchanged.

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d).*/$1/' inputfile.txt
```

for the first character, but there are easier non-regex ways:

```
cut -c1 inputfile.txt
```

Comment: `s/^(\d).*/$1/` can also be written as `s/^\d\K.*//`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-a` (autosplit mode) to split on whitespace, but only modify the first column with your conversion and print the other columns unchanged:

```
$ perl -wane '$F[0] = sprintf("%03b", $F[0]); print "@F\n";' input.txt
```

Output:

```
011 4 5
110 7 2
001 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can split to get the first column and use sprintf to convert decimal  to binary number

use lexical filehandle so that u can avoid closing the filehandle. 

select is used to write the content to a new file.

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<',"num.txt" || die "$!";
open my $wh , '>',"op.txt" || die "$!";
select ($wh);
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
   chomp($line);
   my @aRR = split (/\s/,$line);
   my $bin = sprintf("%03b",$aRR[0]);
   print $bin," ",$aRR[1]," ", $aRR[2],"\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [regex anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to achieve what you want. A regular expression like `^\d` would match a single digit at the beginning of a line.

If you need to support multi-digit numbers (like 15 or 123, for example) you can add a repetition operator: `^\d+` will match any multi-digit number at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. most of them are worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is getting voted down. Is there a problem with it?